# Xcode - Break on exception, but no useable symbols

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, debugging, lldb

I need help figuring out the magical incantation necessary to get usable information in LLDB.

I have some strange behavior that I'm trying to debug, and I can reliably reproduce the issue but I don't yet understand the underlying cause. I noticed there was an exception being thrown, and so I added an exception breakpoint to Xcode.

Exception:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array with userInfo (null)

So, with my breakpoint in place I get the following stack trace:

[image: StackTrace]

This looks super helpful! It looks like there's some funkiness going on with UICollectionViewFlowLayout for the reusable header views... now I just need to... oh. crap. wait. what?

**How do I inspect that array in Frame 1 of the stack trace that's being called with an out of bound index? Can I `po <some memory address>` in the console to inspect it? I cannot use `frame variable` in the LLDB console when Frames 11 - 1 are selected ([from here](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html)).**

The way I read this stack trace is:

1. *(Frame 14)* The fetched results controller has picked up a managed object context change, and calls it's delegate
2. *(Frame 13)* The FRC delegate, an instance of `FHMemberDirectory`, send the message `-memberDirectoryDidChangeContent:completion:` to the view controller `FHMemberDirectoryViewController`, which is a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`
3. *(Frame 12)* The view controller calls `-performBatchUpdates:completion:` on it's UICollectionView instance
4. *(Frames 10 - 1)* Private Apple stuff happens to try and layout the collection view on screen; *I think!*

... Please let me know if I've missed something glaringly obvious! This question is about debugging and I'm hoping another set of eyes or more expertise can enlighten me.

To my untrained eye, this seems like a bug buried in Apple's code, but I still need to figure out a way to work around it. This gist of my problem is understanding how to get useful information from LLDB console in code that is not under my direct control.

Comment: Have you examined the array passed into `-controllerDidChangeContent:` to check what the exception reason text is talking about?

Comment: `-controllerDidChangeContent:` comes from the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol, and the argument is the instance of the FRC making the callback. So, there isn't an array being passed (unless I've horribly misunderstood your question; if so, then I'm very sorry!)

Comment: If you want to inspect the variables of one frame, go to that frame. You are on frame 12 in the image, click on frame 1, open the variables view panel in the debugging area, and see if you locate the mutable array. But on this case, as edelaney05 said, it's better if you check your fetched controller.

Comment: @Jano that's the problem! When I look at any of the frames from 11 to 1 all I get is assembler.

Comment: `frame select 9` should change the frame (or use the mouse in the UI as @Jano noted.  You will get assembler because you don't have the source.  That's expected.  I guess maybe `frame variable` doesn't work for the same reason (you don't have the source with all the variable names) but not sure.  once you are in the right frame then you should be able to do `po 0x123456` to refer to the objects in that frame.  I'd set a break point the last place in your code before the problem happens and check the data that the layout view uses because it appears to be funky in some cases. (released?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experimentation and research, the answer is:

> **With LLDB alone, you cannot get useful symbols or memory addresses to inspect.**

However, you can use the Objective-C runtime to swizzle method implementations and jump into a deep stack trace, therefore giving you a handle to the arguments and return values.

[image: stack trace with methods swizzled in]

Now I have access to the arguments passed in at frames 3 and 5!

(It turns out the argument of `...usingData:` is a private Apple class. I was able to dig up more about the class [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/_UIGridLayoutInfo.h), but nothing super useful. At the end of the day I've filed a [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=3040403) and asked for help with a work around from DTS).